# Convergence of a certain sequence defined almost like an average

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

Prove or disprove: If the sequence $a_n$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, then the sequence $$
\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+ \cdots + a_{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
 is convergent.
The suggested edit is incorrect ...it is a sub n+1 etc.....

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far? (Also is that latter expression a single term in your new sequence? And is the whole sum over $\sqrt{n}$)

Comment: The Whole sum is over root (n) . I have tried a lot of things without any success....

Comment: simply use brackets :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $a_n = n ^{-1/4}$.

Then $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but since $a_k > (2n)^{-1/4}$ for $k = n+1, \ldots,2n-1 $ we have

$$\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k > \frac{n}{(2n)^{1/4}n^{1/2}} = \frac{n^{1/4}}{2^{1/4}}\to \infty$$

Comment: So there is a counterexample , but how is the inequality obtained??

Comment: Yes this is a counterexample.  There are $n$ terms each greater than or equal to $(2n)^{-1/4}$.

Comment: ... so the sum $\sum_{n+1}^{2n}a_k$ is greater than $n(2n)^{-1/4}$.

Comment: You are very welcome.